How to write a reverse HTTP proxy?
So I am messing with  sockets programming and I wrote a forward proxy that works like this:
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

#pragma comment(lib, "ws2_32.lib")

#define BUFFER_SIZE 8192
#define DEFAULT_PORT "87"

// Global variables
SOCKET g_listenSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
bool g_running = false;

bool initWinsock() {
    WSADATA wsaData;
    return WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData) == 0;
}

bool initServer() {
    struct addrinfo* result = nullptr, hints;
    ZeroMemory(&hints, sizeof(hints));
    hints.ai_family = AF_INET;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;
    hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE;

    if (getaddrinfo(NULL, DEFAULT_PORT, &hints, &result) != 0) {
        return false;
    }

    g_listenSocket = socket(result->ai_family, result->ai_socktype, result->ai_protocol);
    if (g_listenSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        freeaddrinfo(result);
        return false;
    }

    if (bind(g_listenSocket, result->ai_addr, (int)result->ai_addrlen) == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        freeaddrinfo(result);
        closesocket(g_listenSocket);
        return false;
    }

    freeaddrinfo(result);

    if (listen(g_listenSocket, SOMAXCONN) == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        closesocket(g_listenSocket);
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

bool isConnectMethod(const char* request) {
    return strncmp(request, "CONNECT", 7) == 0;
}

void parseHostAndPort(const char* request, char* host, char* port) {
    char* line = new char[strlen(request) + 1];
    strcpy(line, request);

    if (isConnectMethod(line)) {
        // Handle CONNECT method (HTTPS)
        char* start = line + 8; // Skip "CONNECT "
        char* end = strchr(start, ' ');
        if (end) {
            *end = '\0';
            char* colon = strchr(start, ':');
            if (colon) {
                *colon = '\0';
                strcpy(host, start);
                strcpy(port, colon + 1);   
            }
            else {
                strcpy(host, start);
                strcpy(port, "443");
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        // Handle HTTP requests
        bool foundHost = false;
        char* current = line;
        char* eol;

        // Look for Host header
        while ((eol = strstr(current, "\r\n")) != nullptr) {
            *eol = '\0';
            if (strncmp(current, "Host: ", 6) == 0) {
                char* hostLine = current + 6;
                char* colon = strchr(hostLine, ':');
                if (colon) {
                    *colon = '\0';
                    strcpy(host, hostLine);
                    strcpy(port, colon + 1);
                }
                else {
                    strcpy(host, hostLine);
                    strcpy(port, "80");
                }
                foundHost = true;
                break;
            }
            current = eol + 2;
        }

        // If no Host header found, try to parse from the request line
        if (!foundHost) {
            if (strncmp(line, "GET http://", 11) == 0 ||
                strncmp(line, "POST http://", 12) == 0) {
                char* start = strchr(line, '/') + 2;
                char* end = strchr(start, '/');
                if (end) {
                    *end = '\0';
                    char* colon = strchr(start, ':');
                    if (colon) {
                        *colon = '\0';
                        strcpy(host, start);
                        strcpy(port, colon + 1);
                    }
                    else {
                        strcpy(host, start);
                        strcpy(port, "80");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    delete[] line;
}

SOCKET connectToHost(const char* host, const char* port) {
    struct addrinfo hints = {}, * result = nullptr;
    hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;

    if (getaddrinfo(host, port, &hints, &result) != 0) {
        return INVALID_SOCKET;
    }

    SOCKET serverSocket = socket(result->ai_family, result->ai_socktype, result->ai_protocol);
    if (serverSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        freeaddrinfo(result);
        return INVALID_SOCKET;
    }

    if (connect(serverSocket, result->ai_addr, (int)result->ai_addrlen) == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        closesocket(serverSocket);
        freeaddrinfo(result);
        return INVALID_SOCKET;
    }

    freeaddrinfo(result);
    return serverSocket;
}

void handleBidirectionalTraffic(SOCKET client, SOCKET server) {
    fd_set readSet;
    char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];

    while (true) {
        FD_ZERO(&readSet);
        FD_SET(client, &readSet);
        FD_SET(server, &readSet);

        // Wait for data on either socket
        if (select(0, &readSet, NULL, NULL, NULL) == SOCKET_ERROR) {
            break;
        }

        // Check client -> server
        if (FD_ISSET(client, &readSet)) {
            int bytes = recv(client, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0);
            if (bytes <= 0) break;
            if (send(server, buffer, bytes, 0) <= 0) break;
        }

        // Check server -> client
        if (FD_ISSET(server, &readSet)) {
            int bytes = recv(server, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0);
            if (bytes <= 0) break;
            if (send(client, buffer, bytes, 0) <= 0) break;
        }
    }

    closesocket(client);
    closesocket(server);
}

void handleClient(SOCKET clientSocket) {
    char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
    int bytesReceived = recv(clientSocket, buffer, BUFFER_SIZE - 1, 0);
    if (bytesReceived <= 0) {
        closesocket(clientSocket);
        return;
    }

    buffer[bytesReceived] = '\0';

    char host[256] = { 0 };
    char port[16] = { 0 };
    parseHostAndPort(buffer, host, port);

    if (strlen(host) == 0) {
        const char* response = "HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request\r\n\r\n";
        send(clientSocket, response, strlen(response), 0);
        closesocket(clientSocket);
        return;
    }

    SOCKET serverSocket = connectToHost(host, port);
    if (serverSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        const char* response = "HTTP/1.1 502 Bad Gateway\r\n\r\n";
        send(clientSocket, response, strlen(response), 0);
        closesocket(clientSocket);
        return;
    }

    if (isConnectMethod(buffer)) {
        // HTTPS: Send connection established
        const char* response = "HTTP/1.1 200 Connection established\r\n\r\n";
        if (send(clientSocket, response, strlen(response), 0) <= 0) {
            closesocket(clientSocket);
            closesocket(serverSocket);
            return;
        }
    }
    else {
        // HTTP: Forward the original request
        if (send(serverSocket, buffer, bytesReceived, 0) <= 0) {
            closesocket(clientSocket);
            closesocket(serverSocket);
            return;
        }
    }

    // Handle bidirectional traffic for both HTTP and HTTPS
    handleBidirectionalTraffic(clientSocket, serverSocket);
}

void cleanup() {
    g_running = false;
    if (g_listenSocket != INVALID_SOCKET) {
        closesocket(g_listenSocket);
        g_listenSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
    }
    WSACleanup();
}

int main() {
    if (!initWinsock()) {
        std::cerr << "Failed to initialize Winsock\n";
        return 1;
    }

    if (!initServer()) {
        std::cerr << "Failed to initialize server\n";
        cleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    g_running = true;
    std::cout << "Proxy server listening on localhost:87...\n";

    while (g_running) {
        SOCKET clientSocket = accept(g_listenSocket, NULL, NULL);
        if (clientSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
            continue;
        }

        std::cout << "New client connected\n";
        // Create a new thread to handle the client
        std::thread(handleClient, clientSocket).detach();
    }

    cleanup();
    return 0;
}

the program uses accept() in a loop, creates one thread per client conencted, browsers open a tcp connection for each http request.Now I want to turn this code to a REVERSE proxy that will work like this, server.cpp, client.cpp. server will listen for browser's connections, receive the requests pass it to client.cpp , in which client.cpp will connect to target hosts, then pass the responses to server.cpp then pass the response to browser.the client.cpp will connect via simple tcp stream to server.cpp.
My problem is: since the client.cpp/server.cpp will communicate through one tcp stream, how can I pass all the requests handle them and send them back to server.cpp?, in which server.cpp for every request received from  browser there is one thread?
My first thought was to have a recv() inside a loop in the client.cpp and create a thread for every request sent from server.cpp, but the problem is that I don't know how to to sent each response back to its specific thread in server.cpp.
Thanks in advance.

a reverse proxy is the same as a normal proxy, but the website owner owns the proxy (normally the client owner owns the normal proxy)

Like Jerry explained, if you're looking to handle multiple requests using a single socket you'll have to add an identifier to each connection.
Each paquet should be like this:
BUFF_SIZE | DATA | UNIQUE_ID

I just made a simple reverse proxy in C++ if you want to check it out:
ReverseProxy. It uses a single socket for all the interactions between the client and the server.
It's in Spanish but I hope the code is easy to read and understand :)

If you're going to send multiple streams of data over single connection, you're going to have to encapsulate the data from each stream. To do that, you'll probably need to frame the data.
That is, read some data in the proxy, then when you sent to the server, add a little header to say the following N bytes of data are from stream M. Then on the server side, you'll need to have a little bit of code that unpacks the data, processes the data from each stream individually, and packages the result up with a similar header to say the following N bytes of reply are for stream M.
To give a little extra assurance (and ability to get back in sync if something goes wrong) you may want to add a reasonably distinctive pattern at the beginning and end of each frame as well.
